# How to nest an if statement in the do of a for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I'm having trouble getting my if statement to execute at the end of my for loop in my batch script.  The code is below...

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/:" %%D in (%DBhost%.txt) do 'if [NOT] %%D==localhost (RD /S /Q "\\%%D\C$\%%D_Health_Check_Logs")'
```

I've searched quite a bit and actually think maybe this is just invalid?  Is there anyway to have the if statement be executed for each do?  I feel like there must be something I'm missing.  I've tried `()`, `{}` and `[]` and none of them make it work correctly.

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: There are no brackets or single quotes necessary around the `if` statement; you should enclose the comparison expressions within `""` to avoid trouble with empty strings... anyway, at first you should try whether the conditional statement works on its own...

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I think you may have nailed it with the conditional.  I'm currently troubleshooting that part as it's not working as it was expected.  Going to keep troubleshooting and will follow up when I get the answer.  I don't see any reason why the conditions shouldn't work if they are setup as expected (which it appears they were not).

Answer (score 1):

Let me doubt that [`rd` command](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) allows UNC paths. Next code snippet should treat [UNC Network paths](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) in a correct way. However, (not sure): it does not look after

- existence of removed directory and
- user's rights to perform `RD` operation…

...

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/:" %%D in (%DBhost%.txt) do (
  if /I NOT "%%~D"=="localhost" ( 
     pushd "\\%%D\C$"
     RD /S /Q "%%D_Health_Check_Logs"
     popd
  )
)
```

Comment: Well, so far I have not been able to get your above example to work although it does seem like that should be correct.  With out the if statement rd does take the UNC path ok.  I don't know if adding it to an if statement would make that different.  I'll keep working with the above and see if I can't get it to work.  Currently it just crashes out at the end on this line.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to everyone.  Looks like JosefZ and aschipfl were both on.  RD does work with UNC paths and I could not get the push and pop working but did not need to.  It was more an issue of making sure the logic condition was working correctly which is was not.  Once I had that set the below code worked like a charm.

Working code...

for /F "tokens=2 delims=/:" %%D in (%DBhost%.txt) do (if /I NOT "%%D"=="%DBhost%" (RD /S /Q "\%%D\C$\%%D_Health_Check_Logs"))